# Is there a way to add extra fields to an association in the ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I would like to be able to model a many-to-many relationship that has extra details about the relationship.  For example:

```
Person: int id, String name
Project: int id, String name

ProjectPerson: Person.id, Project.id, String role
```

Whenever I create the `ProjectPerson` association in the EF, I am unable to add the *role* attribute to the association.  If I create the tables in my DB and then import it into the model, I lose the extra properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe the answer is no. But If you find a clever way to handle this, asside from creating a new Entity Set.  Let me know.

Comment: Funny, I was going to qualify my question by saying I didn't want to create a new entity set either.  Thanks anyways!