# How can I add properties to an association (relationship) using the Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4. I have a many-to-many association (relationship) between two entities:

- Account
- Subscription

The relationship is therefore: AccountSubscription. So an account (over time) can have many subscriptions and, obviously, a particular Subscription type can be held by many Accounts at once.

I want to add properties to this relationship (e.g. StartDate, EndDate, PaymentStatus). I can't see a way in Entity to add properties to an Association table. What is the best way to represent this using Entity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add extra fields to an association in the ADO.NET Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064945/is-there-a-way-to-add-extra-fields-to-an-association-in-the-ado-net-entity-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add properties to associations in EF.  You must simply create a new Entity instead of an Association, in order to mimic an association with properties.

So you would have

```
Accounts (Entity) - [0..1 to Many]  - AccountSubscription (Entity) - [Many to 0..1] - Subscription (Entity)
```